# What is the MdDialogRef replacement in newer versions of Angular Material?

Tags: angular-material

I have the following code in a project I am working on...

```
import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
...
constructor(
    private dialogRef: MdDialogRef<SomeDialogComponent>,
    ...
) {}
```

The problem is this was using an older version of `@angular/material`. The newer versions do not allow you to just use `@angular/material` you have to provide a more robust path. However, when I look through [the code](https://github.com/angular/material) to find this it doesn't appear to be in the code anymore and I can't find new documentation to replace the import.

How do I use `MdDialogRef` in newer versions of `@angular/material`?

**Update**

Seems to be a similar case for other Angular material components...

```
import { MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material';
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, they changed everything from Md to Mat. This works....

```
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```